# Get rows matching the combination of ids in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a combination of ids present in a table1 as listed below :

```
Combi1   Combi2
---------------
1000     26341
26341    26580
1000     26580
```

Now, I have a table2 which has rows as listed below :

```
ID       CombiIDs
------------------
26131    26341
26131    26580
26131    21234
21411    26580
21411    21212
21411    21234
```

I want to get those rows from table2 where there is match of combination of table1. i.e
1000,26341(this combination from table1) doesn't have any row in match as a combination in table 2 whereas 26341,26580 (this combination from table1) has rows matching in table2(i.e.26131).

I want an sql query to achieve this kind of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from T2 T21
inner join T2 T22
on T21.ID = T22.ID
inner join T1 T1
on T21.CombiIDs = T1.Combi1
and T22.CombiIDs = T1.Combi2
```

Comment: It doesn't return me any rows david

Comment: I repaired my query now.